# Turn off Webcam Light on Dell Inspiron 1525

Tags: windows-7, webcam, dell-inspiron

I would like to turn off the Webcam light for all circumstances when the webcam is running.  I have tried configuring the settings to "off" for motion detection and remote monitoring, but to no avail. Is there a registry switch I can flip somewhere or any other solution that someone knows of?

Thank you

Comment: The light is a security feature to prevent unauthorized recording.  It can't be turned off when the camera is sending data to the computer.

Comment: I was wondering...that explains why they don't even give me the option of turning it off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned before, if you CAN do this via software, consider it a bug.  A piece of black tape is your best bet if its the LIGHT that's bothering you.

Comment: I like low tech solutions for simple promlems

Comment: Low tech can give you guarantees that so called hi tech will never be able to give you. That's why nothing can beat voting with pen and paper transparency-wise, for instance.

Comment: I assume that there is no other way right xD ?